# Frequent opening and writing to mongodb causes server to be stuck in nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I created a server via nodejs and mongodb, the problem I'm having is that if there's a high concurrency, e.g. 10k people, the server gets stuck. It seems to be caused by frequent database reads and writes.

```
'use strict'
const AutoBot = require(“./botDev”);
const db = require("monk")("localhost:27017/database");
const dbUser = db.get("user");

AutoBot.on(”join_chat”, async (msg) => {
    const counts = msg.members.length;
    let i;
    for(i = 0; i < counts; i++) {
        const memberID = msg.members[i].id;
        const memberUsername = msg.members[i].username;

        let user = await dbUser.findOne({userid: memberID, isleft: 1});
        if (user) {
            await dbUser.findOneAndUpdate({userid: memberID},{$set:{isleft: 0}}).then();
        } else {
            await dbUser.insert({userid: memberID, username: memberUsername, isleft: 0});
        }
        db.close();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions for optimization? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Never do a query in the loop it can make performance issues

Suggestion:
Need to find all users need to check and execute batch (insert/update)

```js
const user_ids = msg.members.map(item => item.id);
dbUser.find( { userid: { $in: user_ids } } )
```

Filter to 2 lists ( new user list, update user list ) and Update multiple records at the same time instead of only one record.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: Thank you so much, but there's more than 100K users in database, if store them in a map, maybe it's so large.

Comment: I think we don't need to worry about that point. In case you need to deal with big data we need to apply some technique   Ex: Mongo Clusters https://www.mongodb.com/basics/clusters vs Scaling https://www.mongodb.com/basics/scaling